# Hyperledger fabric first network error executing ./byfn.sh: line 175: docker-compose: command not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have the following prerequisites node v10.16.3, go v1.8.1 linux/amd64, Docker Podman v1.0.5, Docker-compose 1.24.1. All are included in path. When I execute "sudo ./byfn.sh up" I'm able to generate the crypto certificates without issues- However error "docker-compose: command not found
" comes in Line 175 when docker-compose is executed in NetworkUp. Tried uninstalling Docker and reinstalling and couldnt find anything relevant in stackflow as well - can someone pl bail me out ?

error

---

./byfn.sh: line 175: docker-compose: command not found
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.

---

Additional info
host:
  BuildahVersion: 1.6-dev
  Conmon:
    package: podman-1.0.5-1.gitf604175.module+el8.0.0+4017+bbba319f.x86_64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 1.14.0-dev, commit: 6ee5ad0285ca12e6c8d0b663d7a8db5323812ef6-dirty'
  Distribution:
    distribution: '"rhel"'
    version: "8.0"
  kernel: 4.18.0-80.4.2.el8_0.x86_64
  os: linux

Comment: can you provide the results when you run this command - 'docker run hello-world'  from the same path and user you are running the byfn command.

Comment: Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 ...

Comment: Also when I try to run docker-compose directly "docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d" - I get this error - "ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://127.0.0.1:2375 - is it running?"

Comment: First I would recommend you uninstall `podman`, then check you have installed docker and docker-compose correctly. All the hyperledger scripts are designed and have been tested to work with docker, not podman.

Comment: In fact I had done those combinations of uninstall and install earlier - Finally I made it work by uninstalling both docker and podman. I installed docker-ce and reinstalled docker-compose. Finally confirmed dockerd is active - systemctl is-active docker with this. It was not active earlier. This fixed the problem - I'm able to now run the script and the fabric-tools images started downloading !